# Can I install PHP on my local development machine?

Tags: php, development

I'm looking to install PHP on my desktop Ubuntu installation to be able to develop locally without uploading my files.

What packages would I need to install to do so?

Last time I tried to install packages for a LAMP stack locally it ended up uninstalling `gnome-desktop`, rendering my machine useless. I'd like to avoid that, hence why this question.

to be clear I don't need an entire LAMP stack locally, I just need to be able to run PHP files.

Comment: I imagine you want a web server like apache?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I don't need apache, as mentioned in the OP I just need to run PHP for development

Comment: Well I think a simple `sudo apt install php` will do. I never faced a catastrophic uninstall doing so.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity unfortunately installing php also installs apache2 and a bunch of other stuff

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command. Note the dash `-` at the end of the unwanted packages:

```
sudo apt install php apache2- apache2-bin- libapache2-mod-php7.4-
```